# Msp directories in production environment configtxgen

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

To generate genesis block using configtxgen we have to pass configtx.yaml file  In that file we have to pass msp directory path of each organization and orderer organization. . Now in production environment all generated msp's of organizations will not be in same directory due to private key and all peers will be in different geographical location .

In such cases how can we pass msp directory path of peers and organizations in configtx.yaml?

Comment: I'm actually looking for the same solution. For right now, I am creating a channel with a single org. Then I go through the process of adding additional orgs to it following the steps here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/channel_update_tutorial.html

Comment: After discussion on fabric channels I found out that configtxgen only looks for cacerts , signcerts and admincerts and not private key . So one solution si to copy certificates of all organization into one location and then produce genesis block .

Comment: Thank you for the information, I thought they used the private keys for the block. Good to know!